# sharepoint content type migration

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Some times ago company intranet has been migrated from SP2010 to 2013

Now when we are creating a new site collections it is always contains content type from the old SP2010. 
And we can't remove them, 
powershel cant even get any details about it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/)?

I have used it in the past to clean up my SharePoint after our 2010 to 2013 upgrade.

Comment: It is good tool if you know which feature the content type belong to but did not help in our case.